# Why is disk access slow through a virtual machine?

Tags: hard-drive, virtualbox, virtual-machine, virtualization

Why is throughput to an external hard drive from a virtual machine much slower than through the host?  Access is generally 30MB/sec from the host and 4MB/sec from the client.  Is this normal?

Comment: I've always wanted to be commenting on a question or answer by someone named `Earl` so that people had to spell out my full name(instead of `ear`) :)

Answer (score 1):

As [Scott Hanselman says](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/VMPerformanceChecklistBeforeYouComplainThatYourVirtualMachineIsSlow.aspx):

> When you're running an OS within and
>   OS and maintaining a FileSystem within
>   a FileSystem, not to mention sharing a
>   hard drive spindle, there's lots of
>   opportunities for things to go very
>   slowly.

If you're interested in improvements (not exactly the whole theory about virtual hard disks) the Scott Hanselman advices are very good.

Answer (score 0):

Well, look at the speed of the virtual usb port in your guest vm. It may give some clues. For instance, there are various usb ports with varying speeds:1.5M, 12M, 480M.